# Use destination flat file from one Data flow task as a source for another data flow task

Tags: ssis, dataflowtask

How to use a text file generated as an output of one data flow as an input to another data flow task which will do the column mapping and push the records into a database table

Comment: Can you post what you have tried and Error Message ?

Comment: Trying to extract certain fields from a text file into another text file, this text file will needs to be used to map the columns and push values into DB table, since there is no column delimiter for the text file being received, need to use Ragged Right format so, the first step is to extract the desired records from text file received into a separate text file and then use this as source for mapping values into DB table, what would be the best way to do that?